# Capturing HTML5 Stream and Extracting Audio for Replay

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, streaming, html5-audio

I have an element like this:

```
<video data-html5-video="" preload="metadata" src="blob:SRC-URL">
```

The src-url is a live stream of a video. Is it possible to some how take the video that's playing, capture just the audio, and stream the audio? (Of course the audio will be slightly behind the video, but I"m fine with that).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use the element's [capture stream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/captureStream).

```
const videoEl = document.querySelector('video');
const stream = videoEl.captureStream();
```

From there, you can use [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/MediaRecorder) or anything else you want that can handle a MediaStream.

Comment: what if the element exists on another webpage? I want to see if I can capture a stream from another webpage and just take the audio.

Comment: @efxgamer That's a totally different problem... you should ask a separate question.  The short answer is, you can't from a page.  You can't generally record something cross-origin.  You can use the tab capture API from a browser extension instead.